# D2C/B2B Commerce Lightning: effectiveAccountId is invalid for Guest

Tags: apex, lightning-experience, guest-user, connect-api

I have enabled guest view and guest can place an order from the storefront. However, I need to create a cart by clicking on an external link. When I try to create a new cart for a guest user I get an error "effectiveAccountId is invalid". For registered users everything works fine. Error occurs in this method, although I do not pass accountId as a parameter here:

```
public static ConnectApi.CartSummary createCart(String webstoreId) {
        ConnectApi.CartInput cartInput = new ConnectApi.CartInput();
        cartInput.name = 'Cart';
       
        return ConnectApi.CommerceCart.createCart(webstoreId, cartInput);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
ConnectApi.CartInput cartInput = new ConnectApi.CartInput();
cartInput.effectiveAccountId = null;
cartInput.name = 'Cart';
ConnectApi.CartSummary cartSummary = ConnectApi.CommerceCart.createCart(webstoreId, cartInput);
```